# Reload table after changing filter

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm developing a small ASP.Net Core MVC application but I'm stuck in reloading a table. In the controller I read data from a database and parse it to the view. On this view the data will be shown by using the modal and a for-each loop. So far so good. On the same page I have a number of input-controls to set the time-window and a range for an ID. based on this filter I want to reload the table after pressing the button "Apply Filter".

After pressing the button I call a JQuery method and form an object so it can be parsed to the corresponding action-method using an AJAX-Post. When I debug I the Action method will be hit and the populated filterobject is OK. In this actionmethod I call the database and it's result should be send back to the view. I can see that the database is called and the list is shorter/filtered.

Any help is appreciated.

**View to populate a table:**

```html
<!-- CSHTML File -->
@if (Model.Count() > 0)
{
    <div class="table">
        <table id="mainTable" class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    @*<th scope="col">ID</th>*@
                    <th scope="col">ID</th>
                    <th scope="col">Block/Sample ID</th>
                    <th scope="col">Timestamp</th>
                    <th scope="col">Usabele rows in file</th>
                    <th scope="auto"></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var sample in Model)
                {
                    <tr height: 10px>
                        <td>@sample.Id</td>
                        <td>@sample.SampleID</td>
                        <td>@sample.Timestamp</td>
                        <td>@sample.UsableRows</td>
                        <td>
                            <a asp-controller="ShadowTable" asp-action="details" asp-route-ID="@sample.Id"
                                class="btn btn-outline-primary mx-1 rounded-pill">Details</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
}
else
{
    <h3>No samples available yet !</h3>
}
```

**jQuery Ajax Code Block:**

```js
$(function () {
    $("#btnApplyFilter").click(function () {
        var FilterObject = {};
        FilterObject.BlockIdStart = $("#blockStartId").val();
        FilterObject.BlockIdEnd = $("#blockEndId").val();
        FilterObject.Start = $("#dtpStartDate").val();
        FilterObject.End = $("#dtpEndDate").val();

        var url = "@Url.Action("GetFilteredResult", "DataOverview")";
        
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: JSON.stringify(FilterObject),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function () {
                $("#mainTable").load("/DataOverview/Index");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**Index Action Method:**

```cs
public ActionResult Index() 
{
    List <Sample> sampleList;

    try{                  // todo: add logging
        sampleList = _databaseAccess.GetFilteredList(-1, -1, DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7), DateTime.Now); 
    }
    catch (Exception ex){ // todo: add logging
        throw;
    }
    return View(sampleList);
}
```

**Action method to read filtered data:**

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult GetFilteredResult([FromBody]FilterObject filterObject)
{
    #region Variables
        List<Sample> sampleList;
        DateTime startDdate = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime endDate = DateTime.Now;
        ContentResult contentResult = null;
    #endregion

    #region Perform some data validation
        int blokStartId =string.IsNullOrEmpty( filterObject.BlockIdStart) == true ?-1: Convert.ToInt32( filterObject.BlockIdStart);
        int blokEndId = string.IsNullOrEmpty(filterObject.BlockIdEnd) == true ? -1 : Convert.ToInt32(filterObject.BlockIdEnd);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filterObject.Start) ==false)
            startDdate = Convert.ToDateTime(filterObject.Start);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filterObject.End)==false )
            endDate = Convert.ToDateTime(filterObject.End);
    #endregion

    try{
        var options = new JsonSerializerOptions(JsonSerializerDefaults.Web);
        options.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
        sampleList = _databaseAccess.GetFilteredList(blokStartId, blokEndId, startDdate, endDate);

        contentResult = new ContentResult
        {
            StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK,
            ContentType = "application/json",
            Content = JsonSerializer.Serialize(sampleList, options)
        };

    }
    catch (Exception){ //PK : Add some logging
        throw;
    }
    return contentResult;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reload the table after clicking a button,you can try to put the table into a partial view,and create an action which will return the partial view.After clicking the button,load the partial view in `<div class="table"></div>`:

Views/Shared/Partial.cshtml:

```
@model List<Sample>
<table id="mainTable" class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    @*<th scope="col">ID</th>*@
                    <th scope="col">ID</th>
                    <th scope="col">Block/Sample ID</th>
                    <th scope="col">Timestamp</th>
                    <th scope="col">Usabele rows in file</th>
                    <th scope="auto"></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var sample in Model)
                {
                    <tr height: 10px>
                        <td>@sample.Id</td>
                        <td>@sample.SampleID</td>
                        <td>@sample.Timestamp</td>
                        <td>@sample.UsableRows</td>
                        <td>
                            <a asp-controller="ShadowTable" asp-action="details" asp-route-ID="@sample.Id"
                                class="btn btn-outline-primary mx-1 rounded-pill">Details</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

View:

```
@if (Model.Count() > 0)
{
    <div class="table">
        @Html.Partial("Partial", Model)
    </div>
    
}
else
{
    <h3>No samples available yet !</h3>
}
```

js:

```
$(function () {
    $("#btnApplyFilter").click(function () {
        var FilterObject = {};
        FilterObject.BlockIdStart = $("#blockStartId").val();
        FilterObject.BlockIdEnd = $("#blockEndId").val();
        FilterObject.Start = $("#dtpStartDate").val();
        FilterObject.End = $("#dtpEndDate").val();

        var url = "@Url.Action("GetFilteredResult", "DataOverview")";
        
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: JSON.stringify(FilterObject),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function () {
                $(".table").load("/DataOverview/Index1");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

action：

```
    public ActionResult Index1() 
    {
        List <Sample> sampleList;
    
        try{                  // todo: add logging
            sampleList = _databaseAccess.GetFilteredList(-1, -1, DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7), DateTime.Now); 
        }
        catch (Exception ex){ // todo: add logging
            throw;
        }
        return PartialView("Partial",sampleList);
    }
```